# VBA, GetPageNumber not working

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code that is supposed to loop through my file paths in A2:A100 (only a few rows are filled for testing), and then populate page numbers for each pdf D2:D100(wherever there are file paths in col A) .

However I am only getting my page numbers correctly for A2 in D2. D3, D4, etc all put the same number as in D2.

Could it be an issue with my loop?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
Sub test()

    Dim AcroDoc As Object

    Set AcroDoc = New AcroPDDoc


    Dim i As Long, pgnumber As Range
    For Each pgnumber In Range("A2:A100")
        If Not IsEmpty(pgnumber) Then
            i = i + 1
            AcroDoc.Open pgnumber
            PageNum = AcroDoc.GetNumPages
            Cells(i + 1, 4) = PageNum
        End If
    Next pgnumber

    AcroDoc.Close
End Sub
```

New code:

```
Sub test()

Dim AcroDoc As Object

Set AcroDoc = New AcroPDDoc


Dim i As Long, pgnumber As Range
For Each pgnumber In Range("A2:A100")
If Not IsEmpty(pgnumber) Then
i = i + 1
AcroDoc.Open pgnumber
PageNum = AcroDoc.GetNumPages
Cells(pgnumber.Row, 4) = PageNum
End If
Next pgnumber

AcroDoc.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to track the row with `i`. It should be the same as `pgnumber.Row`.

Comment: Do you need to close before opening a fresh btw? i.e. should   AcroDoc.Close be inside the If statement?

Comment: pgnumber.Row won't work with empty cells unless you don't mind having gaps in your output. No empty cells then all is good.

Comment: I think the idea is to have gaps. I'd do what @Comintern suggests: remove `i` entirely, and change `Cells(i +1, 4)` to `Cells(pgnumber.Row, 4)`.

Comment: `invalid property` when replacing `i+1` with `pgnumber.Row`

Comment: Huh? `Cells(pgnumber.Row, 4)` works perfectly fine here.

Comment: @excelguy pgnumber in the code sample is a Range object which has a Row property. So that should work just fine.

Comment: @QHarr - I was guessing the gaps are a bug given the description "and then populate page numbers for each pdf D2:D100(wherever there are file paths in col A)".

Comment: tried it with changes, see new code above. Still getting page count of A2 for all cells in col D.

Comment: @excelguy get rid of `i` and put `AcroDoc.Close` before the `Next` as @QHarr suggested and you should be good to go.

Comment: @excelguy I have no idea what AcroDoc is, but presumably it is something Acrobat. Because you do not close the documents you opened in your loop until you have completed the loop, it may well be that AcroDo.GetNumPages will return the number of pages for the first document.

Comment: @ArnovanBoven That seemed to work thanks, it was abit slow though,

Comment: @excelguy no kidding; you are opening files (PDF's i presume). Takes time.

Comment: @excelguy simply out of curiosity: you are building  a list of PDF files and the number of pages they contain, right? If so, why? If you don't mind me asking.

Comment: @ArnovanBoven Yes, well the number of pages aren't really that important lol, but I want to combine multiple pdfs to one pdf. But for example say a pdf A has 10 pages but I only want to combine the first 5 pages of pdf A with 2 pages of pdf b, I want to be able to combine the 5+2 together. I wanted something to atleast count total pages, then from here try to be able to combine like I tried to explain above. I thought getting total number of pages of each pdf may be a start.